# How to pass data to Modal ionic 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, modal-dialog, ionic2

Hello guys Im trying to pass data from my device View to my Modal(device detail View) and bind it to my Modal so if i do `(click)=openModal()` the modal should open with the param which i clicked on. but unfortunately it still empty anybody an idea how i can handle it?

// Data source  & Modal handler

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { ModalController, Platform, NavParams, ViewController,NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import { ModalPage } from '../modal/modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-deviceslist',
  templateUrl: 'devicelist.html'
})
export class DevicesListPage {

  devices;
  device;
  constructor(
    public  modalCtrl: ModalController,
    public nav: NavController,
    public params: NavParams,
  ) {

    this.devices = [
      {
        title: 'Küche',
        items: [
          {title: 'KüchenAid', consumption:'32 W', checked:'true'},
          {title: 'Thermomix', consumption:'0 W', checked:'false'}
        ]
      },
      {
        title: 'Wohnzimmer',
        items: [
          {title: 'Fernseher',consumption:'0 W', checked:'false'},
          {title: 'Stehlampe',consumption:'60 W', checked:'true'},
        ]
      }
    ];
      this.device = this.devices[this.params.get('devNum')];
  }

  openModal(deviceNum) {
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage, deviceNum);
    modal.present();
    console.log(this.device);
      console.log(this.devices);
  }

};
```

//and my modal.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, Platform, NavParams, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-modal',
  templateUrl: 'modal.html'
})
export class ModalPage {

  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    public params: NavParams,
    public viewCtrl: ViewController
  ) {
  }

  dismiss(data) {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The process to pass data with the Modal Controller in Ionic v3 is different from passing data with the Nav Controller. The main difference is that you pass data with a key and value.

You should do this:

`let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage, {deviceNum: deviceNum});`

and on your modal constructor:

```
constructor(public platform: Platform, params: NavParams,public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
    console.log(params.get('deviceNum'));
}
```

Comment: @Alex: did you import NavParams in your Modal Controller? you can find an example here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavParams/ and, really, here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/modal/ModalController/

Comment: @Alexandre do u have an idea why it is still undefined? :( in the link above i i posted my dpaste

Comment: Not really... can you show where you are calling `openModal(deviceNum)` and what you are passing as the `deviceNum`?